# How to add shading for consecutive values on a plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe containing price info over time. I also marked certain periods as upturn or downturn using booleans. I would like to plot the price over time, and shade the areas where upturn == True as green, and downturn == True as red. I am struggling to figure out a way to do this.

Edit: I am trying to plot price on a lineplot over time, using matplotlib/seaborn and would like to shade the "True" regions. I tried doing this using ax.axvspan, but am unsure how to pass the correct indices for x.

Any ideas?

```
                  price  upturn  downturn
2016-12-31   954.623021   False      True
2017-01-01   973.662396   False      True
2017-01-02  1011.492500   False      True
2017-01-03  1020.493750    True     False
2017-01-04  1076.784792    True     False
2017-01-05  1051.258854    True     False
2017-01-06   931.354688    True     False
2017-01-07   865.056667   False      True
2017-01-08   908.179063   False      True
2017-01-09   891.121979   False      True
2017-01-10   900.545208   False      True
2017-01-11   845.028437   False      True
2017-01-12   780.695313   False      True
2017-01-13   805.582187   False     False
2017-01-14   827.220625   False     False
```

Here the dataframe for easy use:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': {Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'): 954.6230208333336,
  Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): 973.6623958333333,
  Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): 1011.4925000000002,
  Timestamp('2017-01-03 00:00:00'): 1020.4937500000001,
  Timestamp('2017-01-04 00:00:00'): 1076.784791666667,
  Timestamp('2017-01-05 00:00:00'): 1051.2588541666669,
  Timestamp('2017-01-06 00:00:00'): 931.3546875000002,
  Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'): 865.0566666666665,
  Timestamp('2017-01-08 00:00:00'): 908.1790625000002,
  Timestamp('2017-01-09 00:00:00'): 891.1219791666667,
  Timestamp('2017-01-10 00:00:00'): 900.5452083333333,
  Timestamp('2017-01-11 00:00:00'): 845.0284375,
  Timestamp('2017-01-12 00:00:00'): 780.6953125000001,
  Timestamp('2017-01-13 00:00:00'): 805.5821874999998,
  Timestamp('2017-01-14 00:00:00'): 827.2206249999999},
 'upturn': {Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-03 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-04 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-05 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-06 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-08 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-09 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-10 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-11 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-12 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-13 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-14 00:00:00'): False},
 'downturn': {Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-03 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-04 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-05 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-06 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-07 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-08 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-09 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-10 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-11 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-12 00:00:00'): True,
  Timestamp('2017-01-13 00:00:00'): False,
  Timestamp('2017-01-14 00:00:00'): False}})
```

Example desired output:

[image: Shaded areas on top of line plot]

Comment: [Shade area in plot with datetime on xaxis (axhspan, matplotlib) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288154/shade-area-in-plot-with-datetime-on-xaxis-axhspan-matplotlib-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a cue from the answers in the comments and set up the background. This is a manual setting, so it would be great if you could decide the background color using upturn and downturn, but that's the current answer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,5))

ax.plot(df.index, df['price'])
s_date = mdates.date2num(df.index[0])
e_date = mdates.date2num(df.index[2])
ax.axvspan(s_date, e_date, color='g', alpha=0.4)
s_date1 = mdates.date2num(df.index[2])
e_date1 = mdates.date2num(df.index[6])
ax.axvspan(s_date1, e_date1, color='r', alpha=0.4)
s_date2 = mdates.date2num(df.index[6])
e_date2 = mdates.date2num(df.index[11])
ax.axvspan(s_date2, e_date2, color='g', alpha=0.4)
plt.show()
```

[image]